# Accessing dataprovider from updateDisplayList

Tags: apache-flex, dataprovider

How can I access dataProvider of datagrid inside the updateDisplayList method of itemRenderer?

I tried following code.I am getting null reference error which seems logical too. As we are just taking owner as Datagrid variable without any connection to 'this' object, dataProvider property of it will be null only. Following is my code related to dataProvider access inside updateDisplayList method

```
var owner:DataGrid;
var duration:Number=owner.dataProvider.getItemAt(owner.selectedIndex).duration;
for(var i:int=1;i<duration;i++)
{
    graphics.moveTo(i*w/duration, h);
    graphics.lineTo(i*w/duration, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try (owner as DataGrid).dataProvider

just typecast it to what you need.

Comment: I tried that but I am getting null reference error which seems logical too. As we are just taking owner as Datagrid variable without any connection to this object, dataProvider property of it will be null only.

Comment: What about dispatching an event on the item renderer that's handled by the datagrid, that will simply pass the dataProver back to the ItemRenderer as a property?